# Отображение кода в разных браузерах.

Tags: html, css

Код: http://jsfiddle.net/qKQ5F/2/

Один браузер делает одно, другой - другое. В мозиле пропадает полностью фон. В одном хроме всё отображается как надо, что переделать, чтобы в IE отображалось также хорошо?

Answer (score 1):

Научиться закрывать span правильно может?

Comment: Спасибо. Просто при копировании первой строки не заметил.  По поводу отображение в разных браузерах что?